# Setting php E_NOTICE within my .module file

Tags: configuration

I want to set E_NOTICE only within the .module files which I create. How can I do it?

I want to catch mis-spelled variable names which are difficult to catch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've never tried this, but if you don't mind modifying core on your dev server you can change `drupal_error_handler()`: examine the results of `debug_backtrace()`, decide if the error came via your module and act appropriately.

Answer (score -1):

You can not set E_NOTICE only to your module files.
In PHP when you activate the notices, it will be activated for all running scripts.

To display errors, warning and notices:

```
ini_set('display_errors', 'On');
error_reporting(E_ALL | E_STRICT);
```

Comment: Will it not generate lot of code from Drupal code which will mix with warnings from my own code?

Comment: I don't get any other error besides mine. Maybe some modules could generate some errors but its not suppose to.

Comment: I guess I should add in the setup.php?

Comment: Drupal uses its own error handler (`drupal_error_handler`) which as I understand entirely bypasses the PHP one, so `error_reporting()` won't have an effect. I've always just modified `drupal_error_handler()` when I've wanted to report `E_NOTICE`. (It also stores it to the log which is neat.)

Comment: FR6 your method does not work and Andy is right. Her method is working and still you go on to say that "I don't get any other error besides mine"

Comment: @AgA I'm just trying to help. It worked for me.